# SQLite ANALYZE breaks indexes

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite

I have a table that contains about 500K rows. The table has an index on the 'status' column. So I run the following explain command:

```
EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE status = 'ACTIVE'
```

Results in a predictable 'explanation'...

```
SEARCH TABLE my_table USING INDEX IDX_my_table_status (status=?) (~10 rows)
```

After many additional rows are added to the table, I call 'ANALYZE'. Afterwards, queries seemed much slower so I re-ran my explain and now see the following:

```
SCAN TABLE my_table (~6033 rows)
```

First thing I notice is that BOTH the row estimates are WAY off. The biggest concern is the fact that the index seems to be skipped once ANALYZE is ran. I tried REINDEX - to no avail. The only way I can get the indexes back is to drop them, then re-create them. Has anyone seen this? Is this a bug? Any ideas what I am doing wrong? I have tried this on multiple datbases and I see the same results. This is on my PC, and on MAC and on the iPhone/iPad - all the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When SQLite fetches rows from a table using an index, it has to read the index pages first, and then read all the table's pages that contain one or more matching records.
If there are many matching records, almost all the table's pages are likely to contain one, so going through the index would require reading more pages.

However, SQLite's query planner does not have information about the record sizes in the index or the table, so it's possible that its estimates are off.

The information collected by `ANALYZE` is stored in the [`sqlite_stat1` and maybe `sqlite_stat3` tables](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#stat1tab).
Please show what the information about your table is.
If that information that not reflect the true distribution of your data, you can try to run `ANALYZE` again, or just delete that information from the `sqlite_stat*` tables.

You can force going through an index if you use `ORDER BY` on the indexed field.
([`INDEXED BY`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_indexedby.html) is, as its documentation says, *not* intended for use in tuning the performance of a query.)

If you do not need to select *all* fields of the table, you can speed up specific queries by creating an index on those queries' fields so that you have a [covering index](http://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html#covidx).

Answer (score 0):

It's not uncommon for a query execution plan to avoid using an existing index on a low-cardinality column like "status", which probably only has a few distinct values. It's often faster for the lookups to be performed by scanning the db table. (Some DBAs recommend never indexing low-cardinality columns.)

However, based on the wildly varying row counts in the explain plan, I'm *guessing* that SQLite's 'analyze' performs similarly to MySQL's 'analyze' when using the InnoDB storage engine. MySQL's 'analyze' does a random set of dives into the table data to determine row count, index cardinality, etc. Because of the random dives, the statistics may vary after each 'analyze' is run, and result in differing query execution plans. Low-cardinality columns are even more susceptible to incorrect stats, as, for example, the random dives may indicate that the majority of the rows in your table have an "active" status, making it more efficient to table scan rather than use the index. (I'm no SQLite expert, so someone please chime in if my hunch about the 'analyze' behavior is incorrect.)

You can try testing the use of the index in the query using "indexed by" (see http://www.sqlite.org/lang_indexedby.html), although forcing the use of indexes is usually a last resort. Different RDBMSs have different solutions to the low-cardinality problem, such as partitioning, using bitmap indexes, etc. I would recommend researching SQLite-specific solutions to querying/indexing on low-cardinality columns).